# Filter version number from string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I found some threads about extracting version number from a string on here but none that does exactly what I want.

How can I filter out the following version numbers from a string with javascript/regex?

`Title_v1_1.00.mov` filters `1`

`v.1.0.1-Title.mp3` filters `1.0.1`

`Title V.3.4A.` filters `3.4A`

`V3.0.4b mix v2` filters `3.0.4b`

So look for the first occurrence of: "v" or "v." followed by a digit, followed by digits, letters or dots until either the end of the string or until a whitepace occurs or until a dot (.) occurs with no digit after it.

Comment: Try `v\.?(\d+(?=\S)(?:\.\d+[a-z]?)*)` see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/VKhoNQ/1)

Comment: @Thefourthbird Looking good. How do I make so it also takes the most simple version "v1"?

Comment: Do you mean in `V3.0.4b mix v2` it should also match [`v2`](https://regex101.com/r/VKhoNQ/2)?

Comment: @Thefourthbird No, but a new example would be `Title v1 V3.0.4b mix v2` where it should match just `1` for "v1". It seems like you need something after the first digit for it to match, which I realize I may have been misleading in the original post.

Comment: Then you could use an anchor `^`. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/VKhoNQ/3) Should the `[a-z]` only be after the last digit  like `3.4A`or could it also be `3.4A.5B`

Comment: @Thefourthbird ok, thank you! The results look correct, however just out of curiosity, is the full match everything until the end of the match? I see the first example says `Title_v1` and not `v1`

Comment: Yes that is the full match and the value will be in the first capturing group. If it can match from the start of the string or there should be either a whitespace or an underscore before the `v` you could use `^(?:.*?[_ ])?v\.?(\d+(?:\.\d+)*[a-z]?)` see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/tCqNd2/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments, to match the first version number in the string you could use a capturing group:

`^.*?v\.?(\d+(?:\.\d+[a-z]?)*)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VKhoNQ/3)

That will match:

- `^` Assert the start of the string
- `.*?` Match 0+ any character non greedy
- `v\.?` Match v followed by an optional dot
- `(` Capturing group

  - `\d+` Match 1+ digits
  - `(?:` Non capturing group

    - `\.\d+[a-z]?` Match a dot, 1+ digits followed by an optional character a-z
  - `)*` Close non capturing group and repeat 0+ times
- `)` Close capturing group

If the character like `A` in V.3.4A can only be in the last part, you could use:

`^.*?v\.?(\d+(?:\.\d+)*[a-z]?)`

```js
const strings = [
  "Title_v1_1.00.mov filters 1",
  "v.1.0.1-Title.mp3 filters 1.0.1",
  "Title V.3.4A. filters 3.4A",
  "V3.0.4b mix v2 filters 3.0.4b"
];

let pattern = /^.*?v\.?(\d+(?:\.\d+[a-z]?)*)/i;
strings.forEach((s) => {
  console.log(s.match(pattern)[1]);
});
```

Comment: Thank you! My last wish. I need `v1a` to return `1a` and `v1ab.1abc` to return `1ab.1abc`. So a dot always need to be followed by a digit and then optional number of letters after that. Thanks again!!

Comment: Try this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/VKhoNQ/4) by adding a character class and repeat that 0+ times

Comment: Genius! Thanks so much :D

Answer (score 0):

**Details**:

`v` - character "v"

`(?:\.)?` - matches 1 or 0 repetition of "."

**Version capturing group**

`[0-9a-z\.]*` - Matches alphanumeric and "." character

`[0-9a-z]` - ensures that version number don't ends with "."

You can use [RegExp.exec()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) method to extract matches from string **one by one**.

```js
const regex = /v(?:\.?)([0-9a-z\.]*[0-9a-z]).*/gi;

let str = [
  "Title_v1_1.00.mov filters 1",
  "v.1.0.1-Title.mp3 filters 1.0.1",
  "Title V.3.4A. filters 3.4A",
  "V3.0.4b mix v2 filters 3.0.4b"
];

let versions = [];
let v; // variable to store match

for(let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  // Executes a check on str[i] to get the result of first capturing group i.e., our version number
  if( (v = regex.exec(str[i])) !== null) 
    versions.push(v[1]); // appends the version number to the array
  
  // If not found, then it checks again if there is a match present or not
  else if(str[i].match(regex) !== null) 
    i--; // if match found then it loops over the same string again
}

console.log(versions);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var test = [
  "Title_v1_1.00.mov filters 1",
  "v.1.0.1-Title.mp3 filters 1.0.1",
  "Title V.3.4A. filters 3.4A",
  "V3.0.4b mix v2 filters 3.0.4b",
];
console.log(test.map(function (a) {
  return a.match(/v\.?([0-9a-z]+(?:\.[0-9a-z]+)*)/i)[1];
}));
```

**Explanation:**

```
/                       # regex delimiter
    v                   # letter v
    \.?                 # optional dot
    (                   # start group 1, it will contain the version number
        [0-9a-z]+       # 1 or more alphanumeric
        (?:             # start non capture group
            \.          # a dot
            [0-9a-z]+   # 1 or more alphanumeric
        )*              # end group, may appear 0 or more times
    )                   # end group 1
/i                      # regex delimiter and flag case insensitive
```